# Display Woocommerce products in tabs and lightbox on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, lightbox

I'm using a plugin that allows me to have tabs filtering on Woocommerce category page. I also want to have a lightbox opening when clicking on a product (and not linking to a product page), but when installing the Category tabs plugin, there was a conflict and it doesnt work together.

So I modified the Category Tabs Plugin code to insert the Lightbox manually and it's almost working. The lightbox opens but I have an error "image path is incorrect".

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters(); ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto">
```

When i make a test with an absolute path of image, it's working well, the lightbox is opening. 
So i'm just missing the right dynamical PHP Path to call the product image, I know i'm close but I'll need a little help for that !!

Thank you in advance for your kindness.

Caroline
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BWGm.png)